# Positive Definite Quadratic Form (limitation)

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

***Show that***

For every positive definite ***q*** quadratic form:

**there are positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $$ \alpha ||x||^{2} ≤ q(x) ≤ \beta ||x||^{2}, \text{for all} \ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$$**

**I'm trying to take**

$$\alpha = \text{min}[q(x); ||x||=1] \ \ and \ \ \beta = \text{max}[q(x);||x||=1]$$

Comment: Your post does not contain a question in its current form, and if you meant to ask for something implicitly, then it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @BenGrossmann is to show that there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: @Andrémash You are on the right track but there are simpler ways. Remember eigenvalues?

Comment: @KBS I do not remember

Comment: @Andrémash Your current attempt is fine. You can use the fact that the restriction of $q$ to $\{x:\|x\| = 1\}$ is a continuous map over a compact (closed and bounded) domain to conclude that it must attain a minimum and maximum.

Comment: @Andrémash KBS is referring to the "Rayleigh Ritz theorem", which states that the minimum and maximum that you are considering are the smallest and largest (respectively) eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix associated with $q$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann My question is how to make it appear $||x||^{2}$ on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The result trivially holds for $x = 0$. For $x \neq 0$, we can use the fact that $q(kx) = k^2 q(x)$ to rewrite the inequality as
$$
\alpha \leq q\left(\frac {x}{\|x\|} \right) \leq \beta.
$$